Angular app components properties remain in memory even after ngOnDestroy
In JS heap Snapshot, the System/Context memory size keeps on increasing. I have an application in angular 13.3.0. I let it run on the system overnight without performing any actions. The size of the app increased from 70 MB to 200 MB. If we go through the section, it has all the properties of the components that should be destroyed. The i section will have all the properties from destroyed components. Even multiple instances of the same properties.
I have unsubscribed all the observables in my component. Any feedback on this issue will be appreciated.



The screenshots for i object in details. The first object:

The second object:


did your application crash? maybe GC didn't run yet? possibly?

@NarenMurali No it didn't crash. But it will eventually crash. As it keeps taking memory and eventually crashes after 3 to 4 days.

just check whats taking a lot of memory, usually getter/setter method used in HTML, or functions in HTML cause overload of memory, check the localhost using the memory profiler, move these methods to execute only once in ngOnInit this might help you!

@NarenMurali I have already done that. Let me add the screenshot of the i section. It consists of the components that should have been destroyed long ago. But even after a day, all the properties are still there.

are you using routerreusestrategy, check if ngOnDestroy gets called on all the components!

my theory is these variables are still being used, try manually, setting these variables to null so that it will get garbage collected for sure!

@NarenMurali Thank you for all your suggestions. I will check if ngOnDestroy gets called on every component.
Also, I wanted to keep that as the last option to set it null. If nothing works, i will do that eventually.

note: ngOnDestroy is for the developer to do the cleanup. It does not mean that the component will be released from memory. It probably is called on every component, but it may be that you do not do the cleanup (subscriptions) properly. It is hard to know, because there's no code from you. A sample code would help.

profiler heap snapshots force js engine to make garbage collection for the measurments to be meaningful. some code from components that spawn those memory leaks would be helpful

I will create a sample project and share it with you guys. Thank you.
